# calculate the output of unlabeled images using a CNN algorithm

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, prediction, torch

I designed an algorithm that uses a CNN algorithm to train labeled training data and compares it to labeled test data. Furthermore, the learned AI had problems writing code to classify unlabeled data and derive accuracy.
First, an unlabeled image was taken and pre-processed, and in the process of prediction, the result was that the torch size was small or that it could not be loaded. In this case, I am wondering which method to use.

The code for that part is as follows.

```
predict_img = PIL.Image.open('./test1/test.jpg')
a= transforms.Resize((32, 9))
b= transforms.ToTensor()
c= transforms.Normalize(torch.Tensor(mean), torch.Tensor(std))
t=a(predict_img)
u=b(t).view(-1, 3, 3, 3)
v=c(u)

print(v.shape)
print(model(v).shape())

single_prediction = model(v)
print('Prediction: ', torch.argmax(single_prediction.data, 1).float())
```

In this part I tried to set the torchsize to be the same because the labeled training and test images are converted to [6, 3, 100, 100], but it failed. Also, "RuntimeError: Expected 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight [32, 3, 3, 3], but got 3-dimensional input of size [3, 100, 100] instead" is output, changing the torchsize to [32, 3, 3, 3], but failed because an error was derived.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer the Runtime error you are getting.

With this error: RuntimeError: Expected 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight [32, 3, 3, 3], but got 3-dimensional input of size [3, 100, 100] instead

You get this error because nn.Conv2d in Pytorch or any layer in the torch library accepts 4 dimensional data in the form of [batch_size, channels, height, width]. However, your input tensor is [3, 100, 100] which is missing a batch_size hence it errors.
Therefore, the way to solve this is to add an extra dimension for the batch_size to your image by doing (Where image.size = (3, 100, 100))

```
v = v.unsqueeze(0)
```

This changes the tensor shape from (3, 100, 100) to (1, 3, 100, 100) which can now enter your neural network
Sarthak Jain